# How to fill a WebGrid on the return of a Json Result in Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My application is in Asp.Net MVC3 with Razor View Engine coded in C#.Net. I want to populate a WebGrid in my Asp.Net MVC3 View.

But my requirement is i want to show the WebGrid on the selection of some dropDowns.
Below is my Json

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public JsonResult getPendingInvoices(Int64 candID, DateTime InDate)
        {
            Int64 timeId;
            var getTimeSheetId= from k in db.TimeSheetInfoes
                             where k.PersonalInformationID == candID && k.TimeSheetDate == InDate && k.InvoicedFlag == false
                             select k.TimeSheetID;

            timeId = getTimeSheetId.Single();

            var getInvoice = (from K in db.TimeSheetTasks
                              where K.TimeSheetID == timeId
                              select new TimeSheetsTaskClass { TaskInfoId =(Int64)K.TimeSheetID, Task = K.Task, TaskDateDay = (DateTime)K.TaskDate, ProjectNameDay = K.ProjectName, Day=K.Day, TaskHours = (decimal)K.TaskHours, ApprovingManager = K.ApprovingManager, OTHours = (decimal)K.OTHours }).ToList();

            return Json(getInvoice, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
        }
```

The Date and the Candidate Id is passed from my values selected.
Below is my Jquery.

```
 $("#MyDropdown").live("change", function () {

            $.getJSON("/../Invoice/getPendingInvoices", { candID: $("#ddlCandidateDispName").attr("value"), InDate: $("#dtpInvoiceDate").val() }, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, TimeSheetsTaskClass) {

                });
                grid = new WebGrid(Model);
            });
        }
    });
```

This is what i have tried.
I want to fill my WebGrid with the Data in my TimeSheetsTaskClass.
Below is my TimeSheetsTaskClass in my Controller

```
public class TimeSheetsTaskClass
        {
            public Int64 TaskInfoId { get; set; }
            public string Task { get; set; }
            public DateTime TaskDateDay { get; set; }
            public string ProjectNameDay { get; set; }
            public string Day { get; set; }
            public Decimal TaskHours { get; set; }
            public decimal OTHours { get; set; }
            public string ApprovingManager { get; set; }
        }
```

Below is how im using my class

```
@model IEnumerable<RecruitmentPortal.Controllers.InvoiceController.TimeSheetsTaskClass>
```

Below is how im Declaring WebGrid Variable.

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
```

Below is how im showing my webGrid in my cshtml.

```
<div id="grids">
@grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```

Please guide how can i show the Data in my WebGrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with a WebGrid. It expects a model. So instead of returning JSON from your controller action you could return a partial view that contains the grid code:

```
return PartialView("_Grid", getInvoice);
```

And then:

```
$(document).delegate('#MyDropdown', 'change', function() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("getPendingInvoices", "Invoice")';
    var data = { 
        candID: $('#ddlCandidateDispName').val(),
        inDate: $('#dtpInvoiceDate').val() 
    };
    $('#gridContainer').load(url, data);
});
```

where gridContainer could be a div containing the grid:

```
<div id="gridContainer">
    @Html.Partial("_Grid")
</div>
```

You might also notice that I have replaced `.live()` with `.delegate()`. If you are using jQuery 1.7+ you should use `.on()`.